# Guest can only access Internet connection for certain websites in vmware player

Tags: vmware, network-shares

My corporate laptop is a windows 7 machine that is able to access both internal corporate websites and other websites such as Google. I'm able to install Ubuntu in the VMWare Player with NAT network mode and visit internal corporate website from the guest Ubuntu system. However, I cannot visit Google or any other websites from the guest machine.. Any idea how I should troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a corporate firewall rule. Many IT departments assign specific IP addresses to each device, and block access to unrecognized addresses. In fact, you should check with IT administration to avoid repercussions: an unrecognized IP address might be viewed as an attempt to hack into the system. If needed, have an IP address assigned to the VM.

Comment: It is strange that I'm able to access all websites on a Ubuntu physical machine via VPN but unable to do so on a Ubuntu virtual machine.